# Azure webjob deploy causes stop/start/stop again/start again

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm seeing a weird pattern where, when I deploy a webjob and start it, it starts, then immediately shuts down, and then re-starts.

It's a continuous webjob. I stop it from azure, and the deploy a new version of it, and then start it up again, and I see this pattern:

```
[03/20/2015 08:55:29 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
[03/20/2015 08:55:34 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[03/20/2015 08:55:35 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Run script 'AdHocWebJob.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[03/20/2015 08:55:35 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/20/2015 08:55:36 > fa2acc: INFO] 08:55:35 [1] INFO  Starting the job...
[03/20/2015 08:55:37 > fa2acc: INFO] Found the following functions:
[03/20/2015 08:55:37 > fa2acc: INFO] AdHocWebJob.TestQueueHandler.ProcessSomething
[03/20/2015 08:55:37 > fa2acc: INFO] Job host started
[03/20/2015 08:55:38 > fa2acc: INFO] Executing: 'TestQueueHandler.ProcessSomething' because New queue message detected on 'testrequest'.
[03/20/2015 08:55:38 > fa2acc: INFO] 08:55:38 [6] INFO  Processing item number 6, cancel token:False
[03/20/2015 08:55:39 > fa2acc: INFO] 08:55:39 [6] INFO  1 sec wait cancel token:False
[03/20/2015 08:55:39 > fa2acc: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[03/20/2015 08:55:39 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[03/20/2015 08:55:39 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
[03/20/2015 08:55:42 > fa2acc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Starting
```

In fact I can recreate this just by stopping and starting the webjob.

It's a pain - because it's causing that first QueueTrigger picked up to be abandoned.

Any thoughts on why this happens, and what I can do (if anything) about it?

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying the WebJob? If you do it from Visual Studio or with a zip file from the portal, I don't think you need to stop or restart, because the deployment does that for you.

Comment: I was doing it from VS (Publish as azure web job). BUt I've also seen this when I just stop and start the job without deploying it too

Comment: What about that "ERR ] Thread was being aborted" in the log? Was there an exception thrown in your code?